# How to have an Eclipse intro open a wmv file instead of downloading it?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

In my eclipse RCP product, I define an intro based on universal template from the framework.  Some of the links are wmv files.  These are opened in the internal browser which prompts for downloading the files.

Is there a way to either

1. Open the link in the user's default browser using only the intro framework.
2. Associate the wmv with a viewing program for the internal browser.

Thanks!
Timothy